# Firewall blocking Port

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall, port, ubuntu-22.04

I am running multiple Webservices on my Ubuntu 22.04 Server and want them to bind to specific Ports which works without problem but when trying to connect it is not working and portchecker returned me that the Port is closed.

I tried to open the port via iptables, which did not work and ufw is not even installed. Do you know if there are other Firewalls on Ubuntu my hoster could have installed? I sent them an email but they just responded with something like "not our problem". When I `nmap <domain>` it says the port is open but portchecker says closed and I cant connect.

Outputs:

`ss -tnlp | grep :444`:

```bash
LISTEN 0      128                      *:444              *:*    users:(("symfony",pid=295662,fd=8))
```

`nmap <domain> | grep 444`:

```bash
444/tcp open  snpp
```

`ufw status verbose | grep 444`:

```bash
444                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
444/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
444/udp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
444 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
444/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
444/udp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

`telnet <domain> 444`:

```bash
Trying <ipv4_adress>...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Thanks in advance for any response!

Comment: "closed" does not indicate a firewall issue. With a firewall it should be reported as "filtered". Please edit the output of your check commands into your question, along with the output of `ss -tnlp` for the wanted ports.

Comment: my recommendation is to use netcat tool to make any port to listen mode, then trying to telnet to the port to check the connectivity. need to mention that telnet only work on TCP .

Comment: @GeraldSchneider
Thanks for your answer! I added the outputs to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it wasnt a Firewall fault. I was just stupid and made a : at the wrong place...